# Filter by string column as a substring of another string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a dataframe by a string column. I would like the filter to return all rows where this string column is a substring of another string. Any searching I do for this problem leads to results about the converse - filtering a dataframe where a string columns contains a substring.

In other words, what I am attempting to achieve is:

```
df[df["string_column"] in "some_string"]
```

or

```
df[df["string_column"].str.is_substring_of("some_string")]
```

**not**

```
df[df["string_column"].str.contains("some_string")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df["string_column"].apply(lambda x: x in "some_string")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[[True if i in 'some_string' else False for i in df["string_column"]]]
```